# Power 100+ 5v LED matrices

Tags: power-supply, voltage, dc, wire, led-matrix

I'm trying to power over 100 LED matrices laid out in a long, single chain similar to a stock ticker on news buildings. I do have the control part figured out but bringing power to the matrices is beyond my understanding.

[image: Stock tickers]

It appears the matrices consume 5v with less than 4A at full brightness (seller did not provide a lot of info). The control unit consumes less than 0.5A, and can control 12 LED matrices so maybe the system should only be designed for 12 at once then replicated if that's easier.

[image: The matrix I got]

My questions are:

- What kind of power supply should I get? I was looking at 5v 60A power supplies which if I am not mistaken should be able to power roughly 15 matrices at once. (see picture)

[image: Power supply picture]

- If using said power supplies (and sticking to groups of 12), should I use the three 5v outputs to each power 4 matrices?
- The matrices each come with power cables capable of plugging into two matrices, but they are not long enough (since I need a single, long chain). Can I extend those cables or should I just replace them entirely?
- If extending or replacing, what kind of wire will I need to support the loads I expect? Would voltage drop be an issue?
- This might be a stupid question, but do I need to set it all up in parallel? It seems that is what the provided cables are doing, but I would rather make sure.
- As a bonus question, would I have issues with the HUB75 8 pins data cable over longer distances as well?

The matrices themselves are 25cm wide, so in the worst configuration power/data would have to travel up to 3m (10ft).

Thanks for all the help, this is really outside of my element and I don't want to fry it all up!

Comment: How expensive is having a control unit? Because, honestly, making your "units" (i.e. control+power+ N·LED matrix) smaller makes your system cheaper to maintain and repair, plus you need less absurdly sized 5V supplies – seriously, 60 A is *a lot* of current, and your cabling needs to be pretty thick to not lead to significant voltage drop if that amount of current is actually drawn.

Comment: The control units are unfortunately expensive and hard to get by, so I am limited by how many I can get. Would having more, smaller power supplies be an option I don't know if I need them all to be connected to the same one? Also, technically each wire coming out of the power supply would only pull up to 8 amps, not the full 60...

Comment: Whether that's possible depends on how the control unit is working.

Comment: I might consider running 12v or 16v to the display, then using small buck converters on each panel to drop to 5v. A synchronous buck would be best. that eliminates issue with voltage drops (11v converts to 5v tha same as 12v) and thick cables (much less current on the PSU), and only adds a smallish ($5-10usd/node) expense to the build.

Comment: @dandavis Interesting, I'll look into it thanks! Would voltage drop be a significant issue with 10ft cables? I intend to put the power supply behind each group of display as opposed to in a central location. Also, by "node", do you mean a single matrix? I'm not sure I can afford $500 of converters...

Comment: Drop is a huge issue if you really draw 70A, but so is heat and cable thickness. I did mean panel as node, but you could cut costs a lot. Use two panels per buck, or use cheaper bucks; many are just $1/ea for something like an lm2596. It might be nice to get bucks with CC/OCP so that an accidental all-white panel won't fry anything. The sign shown probably uses 10% of max on any given panel...

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Each panel should pull up to 4A, and as you say I barely expect to get half of that when in use. Should I consider the entire thing when planning for cables? My thought was since each terminal on the power supply would have 4 panels on it, that would only be up to 16A, plus I could run two separate wires out of each terminal so it would be (I assume) up to 8A per wire. I have found [this person building a square display](http://shorturl.at/hrJR4), which uses similar power supplies and just basic cables of similar length I need, seemingly with no issues even with bright content

Comment: Wire is expensive so are converters. The higher the voltage the lower the current. This allows smaller wire to be used when using converters. This also allows for voltage drop in the power cable without compromising the LED brightness.  There are a lot of on line calculators that will help you pick the wire size when you know the approximate length. Note: some are for a single wire some are with both. I am not recommending but 24V power supplies are readily available and cheap. Assuming loses etc you will need about 1/4 the current from the power supply. Watts is Watts!

Comment: To get the panels to all perform roughly the same you need to equalize wire length to each from the power supply, calculate the resistance of your wire and use that and the current on the wire to calculate volt drop(or you can calculate the other way based on acceptable volt drop to see how much resistance is acceptable.  This will give you an idea of what you're spending on wire and then you can price it based on the smaller wire you'd need at 24V with individual converters.  It could actually decrease your overall cost.  If you can have 5% voltage drop on your distribution that gives leeway.